# Mysql auto increment resetting itself? xamp

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

hey guys was hoping you can help me out.

I'm using xamp as my php development environment and I realised a number of time that my auto inccrement resetets/decreases itself sometimes.

I.e I know for a fact that I had a large table, and then a a week or two ago I deleted all its entries. Today, with new entries, I checked and the first entry had id 1, and the second had id 2 (only two more were added since then)..

Although I doubt the framework has anything to do with this, but I am using codeigniter.

Want to know is this something that is supposed to happen or can should I feel safe knowing that autoincrement does not reset. I am asking this since I am planning to archive data into another table when the table gets too large, and incase the archived data is later required, copy it as is to the new table. This would obviously be a problem if the id already existed there because of auto increment resetting.

Comment: Did you actually `DROP` your table instead of deleting the records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour for certain storage engines. Read the documentation, you will find that this is explained. The increment algorithm does not store a counter value somewhere. Instead it checks what currently is the highest value and increments that to get a new value.

Comment: What engines for example? I tried `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` but both uses the `AUTO_INCREMENT` setting of the table and doesn't reset.

Comment: +1 thats the point -> e.g. InnoDB http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: thanks for the info. But according the the link, auto increment is stored on system startup. So suppose you are using a hosting company (like host gator), and not xamp, the auto increment actually does not reset. Also, any idea which storage engine does not reset auto increment?

Comment: just confirmed, innodb resets auto_increment to highestvalue+1 on mysql restart, while myisam does not reset auto_increment value on mysql restart